# POST to others API from docker container with FAST API

Tags: docker, fastapi

I have a FAST API host in docker container. The workflow of this API will post the data to others APIs which "host on different server". And now the FAST API can be called by another program. But it will get "No address associated with hostname" error when it call to others API, I am thinking maybe something is wrong in dockerfile. Below are the diagram and dockerfile.
[image]

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

WORKDIR /code/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Comment: Are the docker containers on the same virtual network? Which hosts do you use when you try to post to api1/api2? Is this host the same as the running container's name?

Comment: Your Dockerfile looks fine

Comment: @MatsLindh API1 and API2 is not the same machine with my docker.

Comment: The error indicates that the hostname you try to connect to does not resolve its DNS, can you share what hostnames you are using? If they are internal or otherwise non-global-DNS names you have to do some extra steps.

Comment: @krs the host name is inside our company network. But I think I should try adding DNS config.

Comment: yeah your docker container app does not have the DNS setup correctly, try adding your internal DNSes to it!

Comment: You can also check if the hostname is resolving from inside the FastAPI docker using.

Comment: Guys I get "Temporary failure in name resolution" error after I set up the dns server.

Comment: Oh guys sorry I finally solve this problem by configuring the correct DNS server. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am running my docker using Docker Desktop installed on Windows OS. And I notice that Windows doesn't have **/etc/resolv.conf** file. So maybe it will not automatically inherits the DNS settings of the host. And the DNS server ip is different between Windows and Linux in our company.

So I solved this issue in two way.

- Host the Docker in Linux Machine without setting any dns ip.
- Change the dns server ip.